# Clear all the angular application data, session and similar inside an angular application

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application which for some specific user creates an old version load problem.
The project is compiled using the `outputHashing` parameter during the build but this seems not to solve the issue for all the users.

My current build command line (under CI/CD is)
`ng build --prod --build-optimizer --aot --output-hashing=all`

I was wondering if there's a way to remove all the files related to the application from inside the application itself (I was thinking of a button to click that removes all the files of the application, from the storage to the session, cookies, and so on.).

Is this possible? How?
Thanks